# gui display string manipulation

Tags: user-interface, text, graphics, python-3.2

I am learning Python in the hope of impressing my grandchildren - hope nobody is at all ageist!  My project is to get the Hangman game I wrote in QuickBasic to work under Windows7.
I have successfuly prepared a Hangedman figure and written routine to extract random word from a large csv file.  Now I want to write the user interface but attempts to return to an already used location result in overwriting - I am unable to erase the existing string.
The routine following is to explore how to write a string at a given location and erase it for the purposes of the game:

```
# attempt to write and erase text at point locations
# all works OK until returned to location already used
#
# 23 FEB 14

from graphics import *
import tkinter

def main():
# make window
win = GraphWin("Display text locator", 600, 500)
# click 1 to start    
win.getMouse()   
# establish first location
output = Text(Point(400,400),"")
output.draw(win)
# and print simulated hangman word length
output.setText("  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ")
# click 2 for first string replacement
win.getMouse()
output.setText("     ABCZYX W     ")
# click 3 to blank out first string
win.getMouse()
output.setText("                   ")
# click 4 to show new string
win.getMouse()
output.setText(" and here we are again  ")
# click 5 points to new text location and display
win.getMouse()    
output = Text(Point(100,100),"")
output.draw(win)
# first string at new location
output.setText(" here's the new position ")
# click 6 to show new string
win.getMouse()
output.setText("    blank that out    ")
# click 7 to erase it
win.getMouse()
output.setText("                      ")
# click 8 points back to first location
win.getMouse()     
output = Text(Point(400,400),"")
output.draw(win)
# should blank out existing string (but fails)
output.setText("          -                 ")
# click 9 to display new string (but simply overwrites)
win.getMouse()
output.setText(" BACK TO THE FIRST POSITION ")
# click 10 exits
win.getMouse() 
win.close()

main()
```

All suggestions gratefully received (provided no laughing!)
many thanks - jeremy/